# Docker/Kubernetes (Minikube) boot time - mount: unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'

Tags: debian, docker, glusterfs, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a kubernetes/docker container (using Minikube) with a glusterfs volume mounted, but every time I try to start the service/pods I get "mount: unknown filesystem type 'glusterfs'" in the error logs.

However when I start the container without the volumes setup in the kubernetes configuration, add an entry for the server to /etc/hosts, create a mount point and then mount it manually it works fine. Additionally the persistent volume is shown as claimed despite erroring out.

Statefulset

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-development
  labels:
    app: backend-development
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: backend-development

---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: backend-development
spec:
  serviceName: "backend-development"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend-development
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: backend-development
          image: mount-test-gluster
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: web
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - name: certificates-storage
              mountPath: /etc/secrets
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: certificates-storage
      annotations:
        volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: gluster-standard
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20Mi
```

Gluster end point:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: gluster-cluster 
subsets:
- addresses:              
  - ip: 10.108.162.33
  ports:                  
  - port: 1 # port number is ignored, but must be legal
    protocol: TCP

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gluster-cluster
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1 # port number is ignored but must be legal
```

Gluster storage class:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
    name: gluster-standard
provisioner: kubernetes.io/glusterfs
parameters:
    endpoint: "gluster-cluster"
    resturl: "http://10.108.162.33:8081"
```

PersistentVolume configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
    name: certificates-storage
spec:
    capacity:
        storage: 20Mi
    accessModes:
        - ReadWriteMany
    glusterfs:
        endpoints: gluster-cluster
        path: /certificates-volume
        readOnly: false
    persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
    storageClassName: gluster-standard
```

Dockerfile for mount-test-gluster:

```
FROM debian:stretch
MAINTAINER me@example.org

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y nginx wget gnupg2 apt-transport-https

COPY glusterfs-client-install.sh /opt/
RUN /opt/glusterfs-client-install.sh

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

glusterfs-client-install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
GLUSTER_VERSION='3.10'
wget -O - http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/${GLUSTER_VERSION}/rsa.pub | apt-key add -
echo deb http://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.10/LATEST/Debian/stretch/apt stretch main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gluster.list 
apt update && apt install -y glusterfs-client
```

Answer (score 1):

As of late 2016, this is a known issue.  It appears that a fix was attempted but it has not been released, which means it is buggy.  You may have to continue to manually mount it for a while.

You can follow this bug here:
https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/4348

Comment: Thanks for your response. That seems to be along the right path.  

I'm confused about something though, likely due to my own ignorance in this area. That link seems to reference rancher's fork of kubernetes (and an older one at that). Can you tell me how rancher and kubernetes are linked in this case?  

As well as that, I've tried to find the matching file in the kubernetes repo but can't seem to find it.  Finally. I've added an update that states it's with minikube if that matters.